# Debugging with JUNIT4: eclipse "stops" at breakpoints but actually keeps running

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, breakpoints, skip

I'm using Eclipse Juno to debug a java class while testing with junit, but the debugger has been acting flakey. I will reach the breakpoint I want and all seems well with the variable values, but in my console, all of the print statements I set up later in the code are popping out as if I were stepping through it!

*(note: they aren't printing as fast as they normally would if I had simply run it, and the output itself is a bit garbled compared to normal output).*

Somehow, the code is executing through without me pressing a button. If I try to step through, my view of the code and variables is correct, but debugging stops once Eclipse thinks the program has finished.

Something I should probably mention is that I recently put Fedora on my laptop, so I haven't been running eclipse on it for very long and this is my first time trying junit. Is is possible that I need to download something for my debugger?

Comment: Do you have any watch expressions in your debugger?

Comment: Is your code using multi-threading?  If so you might be breaking one thread while other threads continue running.